# Eclipse doesn't render menus or popups

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I can't view many windows in eclipse since they don't properly render. The window opens and has an outline, but the body appears transparent and just displays the window behind it. Is there a resolution to this bug? It makes Eclipse extremely frustrating to use. This is using Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse 4.5.2 Mars. Eclipse was installed from the latest version on the website.

Another, probably unrelated issue, is that autocomplete doesn't perform any kind of prefix matching. It only appears after a period (in Java) and takes 5-10 seconds to load. If I begin entering characters, it never provides options.

Another issue is that many plugins break emacs keybindings and emacs keybindings are completely inconsistent. In some windows that utilize some bindings, but in another window they different bindings or don't use emacs bindings at all.

Comment: Mars is Eclipse 4.5.x., and you should mention how it was installed, whether from the eclipse.org installer, Ubuntu package, or eclipse.org download.

Comment: Updated, although I don't honestly remember whether it was using their installer or another method.